# jQuery: Animate current div only

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I animate elements inside current div only? If user clicks on Edit it should animate the current clicked section only and not all divs.

```
$('.js-edit').click(function() {
  if ($('.other,.hide-content, .show-content').is(':animated')) return;
  // Hide 'Edit link'
  $(this).fadeOut(200);

  // Push down 'other' div
  $('.other').animate({
    'marginTop': "+=400px" //moves down
  });

  // Hide content
  $('.hide-content').delay(200).fadeOut(200);

  // Show hidden content
  $('.show-content').delay(400).fadeIn(200);
});

$(".js-cancel").click(function() {
  if ($('.other,.hide-content, .show-content').is(':animated')) return;
  $('.js-edit').delay(200).fadeIn(200);
  $('.other').delay(200).animate({
    'marginTop': "-=400px" //moves up
  });
  // Show content
  $('.hide-content').delay(200).fadeIn(200);

  // Hide shown content
  $('.show-content').fadeOut(200);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/dafckouL/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use

```
$(this).closest('.section').find
```

for example for `$('.hide-content')`

```
$(this).closest('.section').find('.hide-content').....
```

Comment: ahh so simple =( That was it. It's working now. Thanks! http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/dafckouL/5/

Comment: @brunodd Good Luck :)